# Python - creating a square with asterixes

Tags: python, square

the following code produces an output like this:
Boundary square of stars:

```
****************
*
*
*
*
*
****************
```

I can't quite figure out the code to get the last line (right hand side line of stars to complete the boundary square) to show. And to write a square of numbers inside the  boundary of stars: 
12345
12345
12345
12345
 (bang in the centre)

Can someone help?

```
print("Boundary square of stars:")

for i in range(20):
    print("*", end=" ") 

for i in range(20):
    print("*", end=" ")
    print()

for i in range(20):
    print("*", end=" ")

print()
```

Comment: and then to write inside the boundary of stars

Comment: Hint: you need to do the left and right sides _at the same time_.

Comment: I've struggled with it for a while now -do you mean the second block of code needs to be implemented twice (but how?) arr

Comment: ah and then came the edit of "writing numbers in the center"..

Comment: which you can adapt from Python 2 code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115990/create-a-box-with-text-in-center

Comment: Antii - I want help with my specific code, not to be given a ready made answer! The answers you suggested just have a readymade solution but using totally different methods. Ideally I wanted someone to help me troubleshoot and solve mine! *using the code I already have in place